# Determine if a HDF5 file created with h5py is compressed or not

Tags: python, compression, hdf5, h5py

I have a fairly simple question:

Can I determine if an HDF5 file generated with `h5py` is compressed or not (without reading the data in it)? I need to know it because I would like to change my strategy depending on whether it is compressed or not.

Apparently, I could not find an answer, but I apologise if it was already asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression is handled as a dataset attribute. In other words, some might be compressed, others might not. You DO NOT need to know if the dataset is compressed when reading the data values -- it is handled automatically.

However, if you still want to do this, there are several ways to check.

1. HDF5 h5dump Utility: `h5dump -H -p filename`
2. HDF5 h5ls Utility: `h5ls -v filename`
3. A small amount of Python/h5py code to get dataset's `.compression` attribute.

Python code below:

```
with h5py.File('yourfile.h5') as h5f:
     print (h5f['dataset_name'].compression)
```

Comment: Jeez, that was so easy that I could have literally tried the `compression` attribute without even searching it. Crazy that a simple google search doesn't come up with any result about this. Anyway, just for context, I need to know if a file is compressed or not because I found that if a file has compression the reading of the data slows down any other thread I have running (especially the GUI thread) and I need to change the strategy of reading the data depending on whether the data is compressed or not. This will do it, thank you very much!

Comment: For future reference, check the h5py documentation. It has all the details about file, group, and dataset methods and attributes. [h5py docs](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) The dataset reference is here: [h5py dataset ref](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reference)